# MySQL - Date interval doesn't work properly

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got this query statement.

```
SELECT categories.cat_name, search_logs.created_at 
FROM (search_logs INNER JOIN categories ON search_logs.qry_category = categories.code) 
WHERE search_logs.created_at between '2016-03-20' and '2016-03-21';
```

The problem is that there are records created between 2016-03-20 and 2016-03-21, in fact if I remove the WHERE clause they appear, but if I run the query like that written before Mysql gives me an empty set.

**Edit:** `created_at` is a *timestamp* type and it is stored in the format *2016-03-21 13:18:39*

Comment: What type is created_at and how is it stored?

Comment: Without sample data on which we can repreduce the above unexpected behavior, it will be difficult to come up with any explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you are confused because the column `created_at` contains both a date and a time component.  One solution is to convert it to just a date:

```
WHERE date(search_logs.created_at) between '2016-03-20' and '2016-03-21';
```

However, I think it is better to simply avoid `between` when using date/times.  It is too easy to make a mistake.  Instead, use explicit comparisons with `<` for the second one:

```
WHERE search_logs.created_at >= '2016-03-20' and
      search_logs.created_at < '2016-03-22';
```

Aaron Bertrand (a SQL Server MVP) has written a [blog](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) about this topic.  Although it is directed toward SQL Server, the advice on `between` applies to most databases, including MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `DATE(search_logs.created_at)` or use the comparison operators like this:

```
SELECT categories.cat_name, search_logs.created_at 
FROM (search_logs INNER JOIN categories ON search_logs.qry_category = categories.code) 
WHERE search_logs.created_at >= '2016-03-20' and search_logs.created_at < '2016-03-21'
```